# Remove double quotes from json_encode array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this array and I need to use it in JS for google maps:

```
$punti = array(
array(
    "location" => "new google.maps.LatLng(37.959571, -98.596719)",
    "stopover" => "true"
),
array(
    "location" => "new google.maps.LatLng(37.502230, -97.509929)",
    "stopover" => "true"
)
);
```

Google maps need something like this:

```
[
{location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.959571, -98.596719), stopover: true},
{location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.502230, -97.509929), stopover: true}
]
```

The problem is that using the `json_encode` I have an array with double quotes and maps don't accept it.
 With `json_encode` I have this result:

```
[{"location":"new google.maps.LatLng(37.959571, -98.596719)","stopover":"true"},{"location":"new google.maps.LatLng(37.502230, -97.509929)","stopover":"true"}];
```

How can I remove the double quotes? I tried `str_replace` and `trim` but doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: Store the coordinates instead of the whole object declaration.

Comment: The problem is that you think this was JSON ... which it isn’t.

Comment: What @CBroe stated, it's an Object, not JSON!

Comment: try this: `$json = str_replace('"','', (string) $json);`

Comment: thanks! this worked perfectly!

Comment: @SimoneMarini, as it might be someone else's question as well, I submitted the answer. You may select it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: I am out or Office and I don't know how from phone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Google wants it in that particular format, simply feed him :)

I supposed the json_encoded result stored in `$json`.

So, you can do this:

```
$json = str_replace('"','', (string) $json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to remove Quotaions & commas

var stringWithoutComments = s.replace(/(`[^*]*`)|(`[^*]*`)|(''[^*]*'')|(,)|(<[^*]*>)/g, ' ');
console.log(stringWithoutComments);

Comment: This isn't really all that helpful given that OP's context was a PHP array which needed to be transformed into a string _before_ having quotes replaced, being encoded into JSON and subsequently called via Javascript.